# Submit plugin for review

Tags: plugins

I have to submit my plugin, when I started to search for this, I get to know that first I need to submit my plugin for review in following link

https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers/add/

Here I tried to upload zip file, but it fails saying something like – Add header for your plugin file. I have already added to header to my main plugin file.
 How do I proceed? Please note, I have multiple folders and files for that plugin.

Could you please tell me the steps to submit my app for review?

Comment: Most likely, your header is not complete, or not up to the standards. It can also be a problem with the readme.txt file that also requires very specific structure. Start by reading the guidelines, and check some other plugins to see how the plugin should be organized correctly: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/

Comment: @MilanPetrovic as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your header is not complete, or not up to the standards. It can also be a problem with the readme.txt file that also requires very specific structure. Start by reading the guidelines, and check some other plugins to see how the plugin should be organized correctly: [Detailed Plugin Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/).